# Redmine Version 1 versus 2

Tags: redmine, issue-tracking

Does anyone have any experience with the two latest revisions of Redmine?  I am new to both, and trying to figure out which one to use.  Thanks.

2.0.3 (2012-06-18)

1.4.4 (2012-06-18)

Comment: What are you looking for? Why are you considering a 1.* version?

Comment: I suppose I take that as a recommendation for 2.  2 is new, and I've extensively searched on pros/cons of each and haven't found any.  Than you

Comment: Also, I currently use 5.X Centos and not 6.X, so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.4.4** is the stable old Redmine branch with fewer features than the **2.x** branch. Only bugfixes came into the branch.

When you have the choice of a clean Redmine install, use the **2.0.3** version. But you should look at the plugins, as some of them are not compatible with Redmine 2.x.